# Is there any difference between `if bool(x)` and `if x` in Python?

Tags: python

I've come across some code that reads:

```
if bool(x):
    doSomething
```

I think that the following would do the same job:

```
if x:
    doSomething
```

[The reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) says that it evaluates the suite if the test expression

> is found to be true

The reference says of Boolean expressions:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements are used
>   by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as
>   false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and
>   containers ... All other values are interpreted as true.

The [reference](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool) says of the `bool()` function:

> Convert a value to a Boolean, using the standard truth testing procedure

So are the two above identical or is there some extra subtlety to it?

Comment: Simply follow the first link in the docs about if and you'll have your answer.

Comment: I know what the reference says. That's why I quoted it. As the reference says, it is not a specification, and I am asking if my reading of the docs is correct.

Comment: No, it links you to _ _nonzero()_ _

Comment: Thank you. That is not the first link in the docs about if, but does contain the vial sentence.

Comment: If you want to quote "Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation bool();" as an answer, I'll tick it. Other answers have not made reference to this.

Comment: While the code is functionally equivalent, there's also python style guidelines.  `if x:` is the pythonic way to write the expression according to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).   (Search for `Yes:   if greeting:`).  Casting to `bool` is silly.  Also see [Code Like A Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#testing-for-truth-values).

Comment: Oh, I'm fully aware that's stylistically odd. But I was coming from the point of view of "I have found this" not "I want to do this".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if` will use `__nonzero__()` if available, as does `bool()` when testing a value for truth. So **yes**, the behaviour is equivalent.

From the documentation:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
>   used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
>   as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings
>   and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
>   and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the
>   **`__nonzero__()`** special method for a way to change this.)

[`object.__nonzero__(self)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool();` should return False or True, or their integer equivalents 0 or
>   1. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero.
>   If a class defines neither  `__len__()` nor `__nonzero__()`, all its
>   instances are considered true.

Comment: This wasn't the first answer, but it does contain a categorical link between the `if` and `bool()` functions, so marking correct.

Comment: `__nonzero__` is known as `__bool__` in python 3.x.

Answer (score 15):

Objects are implicitly converted to bool type when they are placed in an if statement. So, for most purposes, there's no difference between `x` and `bool(x)` in an `if` statement. However,  you will incur extra overhead if you call `bool()` because you are making a function call. Here's a quick test to demonstrate this:

```
In [7]: %timeit if(''): pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit if(bool('')): pass
1000000 loops, best of 3: 235 ns per loop
```

Comment: your code has mismatched loop checkers.... one is 10,000,000 the other is 1,000,000

Comment: @InbarRose: no, that's just how many times `timeit` looped.  It decided to do fewer in the second case because it was 10 times slower.  The `per loop` is the important number.

Comment: The amount of times the %timeit function repeats the code depends on how slow the code is.

Answer (score 3):

any Object that you put in an `if` statement will be converted to a bool based on some internal python checker, normally not an issue, there is no difference between `bool(x)` and `(x)` when inside an `if` statement.

however, the reason `bool(x)` exists is for cases such as:

`return bool(x)`

which would return "`true` or `false`" based on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no difference, if x is either '', None, 0 or False it will be converted to False.

Comment: And `[]` and `{}` and `set()` and... the list goes on. (Any object can be defined with a `__nonzero__` method (or `__bool__` for Python 3) and this controls the behaviour of `if x`.)