# Numpy : Get the element of array which contains True on comparions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np  
import re

list1= ['651ac1', '21581', '13737|14047', '22262', '12281', '12226', '61415', '61495']
regexp = '[a-zA-Z]'
selection = np.array([bool(re.search(regexp, element)) for element in list1])
if True in selection:
    #get_element_containing_true
```

The `selection` looks like this:

```
selection
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

I want to get the element of array which contains True. How do I get this?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: This worked form me : **np.array(list1)[selection]**

Comment: I guess then @MSeifert's solution worked for you. Consider accepting it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually need `numpy` here (see [@Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41980132/5393381) if you don't)? If you do, you could convert the `list1` to `np.array` and index:

```
np.array(list1)[selection]
```

This is called [`boolean array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). Just in case you're interested.

---

Just a performance tip: If you use a regular expression several times: compile it and reuse that compiled one:

```
regexp = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]')
selection = np.array([bool(regexp.search(element)) for element in list1])
```

That could be much faster and easily combined with the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could directly get those within the `list-comprehension` -

```
[element for element in list1 if bool(re.search(regexp, element))]
```

On a closer look, With the search method, we get an object for a match :

```
In [175]: re.search(regexp, list1[0])
Out[175]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7fc30bac1c60>
```

For a no match case, we get `None`.

According to the [`definitions of booleans`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans) :

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
>   used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
>   as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings
>   and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
>   and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.
>   User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a
>   **bool**() method.

So, if the search method results are directly fed to `IF`, we get objects for matches and `None` for no matches. As such using the definition, with the `IF`, a match would be evaluated as `True` and `False` otherwise. Thus, we can skip the bool() there and have a simplified version, like so -

```
[element for element in list1 if re.search(regexp, element)]
```

Comment: No need to cast with `bool()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Seems like it. But that output with `re.search(regexp, list1[0])` is giving out something that I don't fully understand, so just to be safe there I guess :)

Comment: But `if` converts to `bool` anyway, it's the same! see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885382/is-there-any-difference-between-if-boolx-and-if-x-in-python

Comment: @Chris_Rands Upon some research, found out few things and added accordingly there :) Not really familiar on those fronts, so hoping those statements are correct.